# How to convert Georgian date from database to Persian date in razor view? - Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I stored `Giorgione Date` in the database and must show `Persian Date` to users. I write this but an error occurred.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  @General.PersianNumDate(Convert.ToDateTime(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostDate)))
}
```

Error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

How can I Convert `PostDate` from Georgian to Persian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found solution:

```
@General.PersianNumDate(Convert.ToDateTime(item.PostDate))
```